# one .html file not getting logo.png file from the correct location

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I'm working on creating a web application running in python3.10 using Django, most pages are working as expected but one page does not display the logo correctly, I get the following error:

Not Found: /products/media/logo.png
[09/Apr/2023 11:45:03] "GET /products/media/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3536

The issue with this is that all of my .html files are currently using a base.html file and all of the other extend that to maintain the sites formatting using

{% extends 'base.html' %}

the path to the logo file only exists in the base.html file and only one page doesn't load the image correctly, ALL of the others do.

it's also odd because there is no 'products/media' path in my project, in fact there isn't even a products folder so I'm not sure why it's trying to use this path, I've double and triple checked everything I can think of and I can't figure out why this page is attempting to get the logo.png file from a different location than all the other pages, for reference the html for this page is very simple:

```
`{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ toy.name }}</h1>
  <p>{{ toy.description }}</p>
  <p>Price: ${{ toy.price }}</p>
  <img src="{{ toy.image.url }}" alt="{{ toy.name }}">
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'cart:cart_add' toy.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}`
```

I've tried manually adding a copy of the logo.png and creating the location shown in the error above and it still gives a file not found error, I would expect that this file would have the same functionality as the other pages that are using base.html but for some reason it is not behaving the same

Comment: Can you share the settings regarding the media in the `settings.py`?

Comment: BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

Answer (score 0):

so changing the MEDIA_URL didn't have any effect, BUT I wasn't using a reference to the that variable in my home.html file, I just had it set to

```
src="media/logo.png"
```

when I added the leading slash to this so it was

```
src="/media/logo.png"
```

it started working